# Android: ImageButton not showing states pressed

Tags: android, android-layout, imagebutton

I have an ImageButton and I swear I have everything set up right but it is not showing the different icon when a state is pressed.  Here is what I have.

ImageButton

```
        <!-- HOME BUTTON -->
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/home"
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:contentDescription="Home" 
        android:src="@drawable/title_home"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:onClick="onClickHome" />
```

Title Home

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/title_home_pressed"/>
<item android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/title_home_pressed"/>
<item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/title_home_pressed"/>
<item android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/title_home"/>
</selector>
```

And yes these are all valid images, and they are different. title_home is the only one that is showing up.

I would appreciate any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice how you are referring to @drawable/title_home in the first block of code, but you are intending to refer to the xml file. Although in the second block of code you are referring to another @drawable/title_home which I am assuming is an image.

Because of this I can only assume that from your information your first block of code is reading the image and not the xml file. To fix this, I believe changing the names of one of them would help.

Comment: You are absolutely right!  Ha, sometimes you just need another set of eyes to point out the obvious!

Answer (score 0):

```
android:src="@drawable/title_home"

<item android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/title_home"/>
```

Same name. Change your xml file name to title_home_btn_selector.
Then make the first one as

> android:src="@drawable/title_home_btn_selector"